# Can Company take away "courtesy privilege" whenever they feel like it?

Tags: united-states, company-policy

As an intern working in the local government organization(city-level) in the US, I noticed that I was not getting paid for some of the holiday(Christmas and New Year) while got paid for the rest of the holiday(MLK, Thanksgiving etc).

I then talked to my director about it who then contacted the payroll department. The director of payroll informed that intern does not receive paid holiday benefits. It is a courtesy.

So i was wondering, so it is a courtesy, can company just take it away whenever they feel like it?

Comment: Did the take the privilege away from all interns or just from you?

Comment: This is either a matter of law, or of company policy.  As such, it is out of the purview of this stack.

Comment: Check if paid holiday is in you employment contract.

Comment: @TheSnarkKnight: In which case, it may be better located on the Law stackexchange.

Comment: @Lumberjack i am the only intern in our department, so I wouldn;t know.

Comment: @Paparazzi good call, i will do it later today

Comment: This question has nothing to do with navigating the workplace, it is asking for the dictionary definition of "courtesy".

Answer (score 4):

Yes they can. There's no legal requirement that any specific class of employees get holiday pay.

The only way it would be actionable is if you're specifically excluded but other people in your class (interns) do.  Even then, they could put certain requirements to get it such as having worked there a certain time or even merit as long as they don't exclude based on protected reason (gender, race, religion, age, etc.)

But regardless, the crux of the issue is that your company's payroll director said what was the case and we're not equipped to answer legal questions here, which is basically what you're asking.

Comment: +1 Agree completely.  The key is "fairness."  If the company has discriminated against an individual there might be legal repercussions.

Comment: You are right. I was also informed that in order to receive holiday pay, I have to work the day before and the day after. So for instance, if this Wednesday is the holiday, then i have to work on Tuesday and Thursday to receive the paid holiday privilege. I dont know how common this type of policy is in the workplace, but it is definitely the first time I have hear it.

Comment: @aDev in my experience, that's not uncommon for the USA. Both my previous employers have had the same policy.

Comment: @aDev It's **very** common in the US. The only way around it is if you use vacation for one of those days, but you're an intern so that's really not a possibility.